# Writing to the StepExecutionContext in multi-threaded steps in Spring Batch

Tags: multithreading, spring, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch and I've created a tasklet that is run by using a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`. In this step, I am retrieving the `StepExecutionContext` with

```
@BeforeStep
public void saveStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
}
```

In the processing method of the tasklet, I try to update the context:

```
stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put("info", contextInfo);
```

This leads to `ConcurrentModificationException`s on the `stepExecution`.
How can I avoid these and update my context in this multi-threaded environment?

Comment: please provide more infos, e.g. which spring batch version and the source of the tasklet implementation

Comment: SpringBatch 2.1.8. What details of the implementation do you need to answer the question?

Comment: if you implemented a tasklet with 'org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet' you would need to implement 'RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext)' and inside the chunkContext is a modifiable stepExecutionContext, you use the BeforeStep Annotation to get the stepExecution, so i am not sure how your "tasklet" looks like or if it even is a "Tasklet"

Answer (score 1):

The step execution context is a shared resource. Are you really trying to put one "info" per thread? Depending on your context, there are many ways to solve this, since it is a threading issue, not Spring batch.

1) if there is one info per thread, have the thread put a threadlocal in the context (once), and then use the threadlocal to store the "info".

2) if context info is "global", then you should do the put in a synchronized block and check for its existence before putting.

Hope this helps.